# didChangeAppLifecycleState is not working Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, application-lifecycle

I have the app of more than 20 screens , I want to perform a task if user is inactive/idle for a certain time.
I am trying to get the app's lifecycle at root of app. But i am not getting print statements on my logcat. What wrong I have done here?

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
 

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver{


  @override
  didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        print('app resumed');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        print('app inactive');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        print('app paused');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        print('app detached');
        break;
    }
  }
   @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();
    _initializeTimer();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
  }
```

Comment: did you initialize widget binding observer in main.dart like this WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();  ?

Comment: yes! I have edited the question too

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be because your app is not changing its lifecycle state, here's what is said for the `AppLifecycleState.inactive` and `AppLifecycleState.paused` in the documentation:

> **inactive** The application is in an inactive state and is not receiving user input.
>
> On iOS, this state corresponds to an app or the Flutter host view
> running in the foreground inactive state. Apps transition to this
> state when in a phone call, responding to a TouchID request, when
> entering the app switcher or the control center, or when the
> UIViewController hosting the Flutter app is transitioning.
>
> On Android, this corresponds to an app or the Flutter host view
> running in the foreground inactive state. Apps transition to this
> state when another activity is focused, such as a split-screen app, a
> phone call, a picture-in-picture app, a system dialog, or another
> window.
>
> Apps in this state should assume that they may be paused at any time.
>
> **paused**
> The application is not currently visible to the user, not responding to user input, and running in the background. When the
> application is in this state, the engine will not call the
> Window.onBeginFrame and Window.onDrawFrame callbacks. Android apps in
> this state should assume that they may enter the suspending state at
> any time.

[source](https://docs-flutter-io.firebaseapp.com/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html)

So basically none of these state will became active if your user is only waiting idly. The workaround that comes to my mind would be to use a `RestartableTimer` which would trigger the action you want after a certain "inactive" period of time and depending on how you've made your screen you could wrap it inside a `GestureDetector` to catch your user's input and reset the timer.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:async/async.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late final _timer =
      RestartableTimer(const Duration(seconds: 2), _timerAction);

  void _timerAction() {
    print("User is idle");
  }

  void _resetTimer() {
    print("Caught event, reset timer");
    _timer.reset();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timer.reset(); // Start the timer
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _resetTimer,
      child: Scaffold(),
    );
  }
}
```